# Sending ClientCertificates from HttpWebRequest via Fiddler

Tags: fiddler, identityserver3, client-certificates

I am trying to send out a WebRequest request like https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/clientCerts.html specifies with a handler containing the Client Certificate.

I've gotten to the point that i have determined that the ClientCertificate is just not being sent through fiddler, so it is not read in the [ServerVariables["CERT_FLAGS"]](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpClientCertificate.cs) when the Owin LoadCertificate is called.

So i have removed all the steps from the process except (IdentityServer3.Samples/source/Clients/ClientCertificateConsoleClient/Program.cs)

```
async Task<TokenResponse> RequestTokenAsync()
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2("Client.pfx");

    var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

    var client = new TokenClient(
        Constants.TokenEndpoint,
        "certclient",
        handler);

    return await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("read write");
}
```

but I am still not seeing in fiddler in the raw request the certificate. I have looked at the source code for [HttpWebRequest](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs) and only see it handles the ClientCertificate in the GetConnectionGroupLine, and then its a hash code which i also don't see in fiddler. I'm working with Windows 7 and i have turned on the iis client certificate mapping authentication and enabled the setting in iis express applicationhost in the 2015 .vs subfolder and the primary one in my docuemnts. What am I missing here?

reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f88a23f2-3dbe-4202-baf2-a5b05b027fe6/httpwebrequest-not-sending-client-certificate-to-server?forum=netfxnetcom
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3220 - can't really find this on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: Your problem (at this point) is Fiddler not HttpWebRequest/dotnet.** (Edited to clarify.)

1. **Fiddler doesn't display TLS info including certs.** Fiddler works on, and displays in numerous formats, the HTTP-level data (requests and responses, including application data). When HTTPS transports this HTTP data over SSL/TLS, Fiddler does not display the SSL/TLS-specific data, which in addition to server and optional client certificates (currently) includes version, suite, possibly compression, curve, format and next-protocol negotiation, nonces, ephemeral keys, renegotiation control, signature algorithm control, server name indication, ticket, and other crypto options like encrypt-then-mac and extended-master-secret. The "raw" tab displays all the HTTP data without interpretation, but not the SSL/TLS data.
2. **Fiddler doesn't request client auth.** An SSL/TLS session uses a client certificate to perform client authentication only when requested by the server, and when your client connects to the real IdentityServer it presumably requests this. But when Fiddler is used, there is one SSL/TLS session from the client to Fiddler, and an entirely separate SSL/TLS session from Fiddler to the server. On the session from your client to Fiddler, Fiddler does not request client authentication, so your client doesn't and can't send or use its certificate.
3. **Client auth can't be relayed anyway.** If Fiddler did request client auth on the session from your client, it couldn't use that information to authenticate the session to the real server. Client auth doesn't just send the client cert, it also uses the private key to sign the concatenation (called a transcript) of the handshake messages. Since the handshake between your client and Fiddler and between Fiddler and the server are quite different, this signature is invalid for the server-side handshake and sending it would (correctly) be rejected as invalid by the server.
4. **Instead *Fiddler* can do the client auth.** If you want to route HTTPS traffic using client auth through Fiddler, you need to instead configure *Fiddler* to do the client auth on the session with the server; for a fixed setting you can just drop the identifying certificate in Fiddler's config directory, for per-session settings you need to write some FiddlerScript. The private key (and chain) needs to be in the Windows cert store, not (just) in a file. See:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/RespondWithClientCert
https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsclientcerts.asp
[Fiddler: Respond to Requests Requiring a Client Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451892/fiddler-respond-to-requests-requiring-a-client-certificate) (on SO) 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72916/can-fiddler-decrypt-https-traffic-when-using-elliptic-curves-client-cert-authe

If your actual problem is getting the client to support client auth when NOT using Fiddler, you need to take Fiddler out of the situation and use other debugging tools like a network trace.